# Load one-time use terminator layouts

Tags: terminator

What I would like to accomplish is to create an script/program that writes a terminator config file with a one-time use layout and then tell terminator 'use this config file instead of ~/.config/terminator/config' and load layout 'tmp' from it.

#### Use case:

Often I have to ssh into many servers to do exactly the same operation in all of them, the set of servers could vary so I could not possibly have an static layout that I could use all the time. If I could create such temporary layout with each terminal ssh-ing into a different server (using ssh @server as default command) and grouping all the terminals I could get my job done in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in `man terminator_config`. In my particular solution was to define

`export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="/tmp";`

as part of my own script, then at the very last part of the script
invoke the terminator instance, this way the variable will be only defined inside that bash/terminal instance (and its childs) and will not contaminate the default terminator's behavior. Below a pseudo-code example:

**many_ssh_terminals.sh:**

```
 export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="/tmp";
 mkdir > /tmp/terminator;
 write_config_with_layout > /tmp/terminator/config; 
 terminator -l tmp_layout
```